# Are these two loops always equivalent

Tags: java, loops

In the Java programming language, are the following two loops equivalent for any expression *exp* and and loop body *body*? Only side condition should be that the freshly introduced variable *b* does not appear elsewhere in the method (and does not hide an attribute, ...)

```
while(exp) {
    body
}
```

and

```
for(boolean b = exp; b; b = exp) {
    body
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be b==exp and not b=exp?

Comment: @Ricky Bobby since b is a boolean no.

Comment: @Voo thx, I didn't knew that.

Comment: @Captain. I inversed everything in my head... I didn't realise the second part of the for argument was the condition... my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, under those assumptions.

The `for` construct checks the condition before the first iteration, so if `b` is `false`, then the body will never be executed.  To put it another way, in your code example, `exp` is evaluated precisely once before each loop iteration, and the result used to decide whether to execute that iteration or not.

<s>But why would you want to write code like this?</s>

Comment: Ordinarily not. However a very similar looking `for()` construction can be used to collapse some tricky do/while loops when your conditions solely depend on some predicate expression (but crucially not on the computation of the for body). E.g. when reading files line by line you might use something like: `for(String s=reader.readLine(); s!=null; s = reader.readLine())`.

Comment: @user: Yes, that's a reasonable example.

Comment: Not counting =)   while ( null!= (s = reader.readLine()))  is fine with me. Maybe a corner case.

Comment: @Captain: I guess the distinction is that the scope of `s` "leaks" out of the loop if you do it that way.

Answer (score -1):

No they are not. Make your code readable.

One is **for** counting

The other one is for waiting for a condition to be true.

Comment: The English semantics are irrelevant here; the Java semantics will be equivalent.

Comment: He's not asking if the semantics are the same, he's asking whether those two bits of code are equivalent.

Comment: The regular for loop is absolutely not restricted to counting.

Comment: Agree with @Michael.  One non-counting idiom is to traverse e.g. a linked-list: `for (Node n = head; n != null; n = n->next) { ... }`.

Comment: Yep you can use it just fine for iterating through a linked list or as an endless loop - though I generally would agree that there's some useful semantical difference between the two that's nice to uphold. But that's subjective.. Edit: Damnit oli was faster ~

Comment: @Oli how would that be not counting!! My flabber is ghasted

Comment: @Captain Giraffe Umn.. since there are no numbers involved, the end point is unknown (if I give you the head of a linked list you won't know how many elements there are).. where is THAT counting for you?

Comment: @Captain: In what way is that counting?  There is nothing equivalent to an index or a number in my example.

Comment: @Voo really? Lets move this to chat

Comment: @Oli It seems like we could just answer in turn here ;-)

Comment: @Oli Well If you dont feel +1 is counting I'm outta here

Comment: @Oli "The for construct checks the condition before the first iteration" I would be trying hard not to find the +1 in this.

Comment: @Captain: What are you talking about?  `for (a; b; c) { ... }` is approximately equivalent to `a; while (b) { ... c; }`.  No +1 involved.

Comment: @Oli well throw in another { statements } and you are grammatically correct. I love my sick nurse.

Comment: @Kublai You don't like counting either?

Comment: @Captain - Just making light of the situation :P

Comment: @Kulai Khan How did you get that in the Mortal Combat voice?